# Setting up host config for adaptive card in bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, rendering, adaptive-cards, adaptive-design

I wanted to know how to setup hostconfig to my adaptive card for styles. Im new to bot framework and wanted to know how to implement host config for adaptive card in c# , even checked [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/javascript/host-config].
this is my adaptive card below  card.json and guide me step by step creating the host config for the below card.

```
 {
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.3",
"actions": [
  {
    "type": "Action.Submit",
    "title": "Sign-up",
    "data": "${signin}",
    "id": "7"
  },
  {
    "type": "Action.Submit",
    "title": "Password Reset",
    "data": "${preset}",
    "id": "8"
  }
],
"body": [
  {
    "type": "TextBlock",
    "wrap": true,
    "text": "Menu",
    "style": "heading",
    "fontType": "Default",
    "color": "Good",
    "weight": "Bolder",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "type": "ActionSet",
    "actions": [
      {
        "type": "Action.ShowCard",
        "title": "Sign-in",
        "card": {
          "type": "AdaptiveCard",
          "body": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Username",
              "label": "Your name (Last, First)",
             // "validation": "^[A-Z][a-z]+, [A-Z][a-z]+$",
              "data": "${username}",
              "wrap": true,
              "id": "3"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Password",
              "wrap": true,
              "id": "5"
            },
            {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "placeholder": "***********",
              "style": "padding=2px",
              "id": "6"
            }
          ]
        },
        "id": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
```

}

Comment: I don't know if you are still needing help on this, but this is dependent on what you are using for the client and whether it supports using adaptive cards. If you are using BotFramework-WebChat, then this is possible and I can provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way.

```
// Construct programmatically
renderer.HostConfig = new AdaptiveHostConfig() 
{
  FontFamily = "Comic Sans",
  FontSizes = {
    Small = 15,
    Default = 20,
    Medium = 25,
    Large = 30,
    ExtraLarge= 40
  }
};

// Or parse from JSON
renderer.HostConfig  = AdaptiveHostConfig.FromJson(@"{
""fontFamily"": ""Comic Sans"",
""fontSizes"": {
    ""small"": 25,
    ""default"": 26,
    ""medium"": 27,
    ""large"": 28,
    ""extraLarge"": 29
  }
}");
```

Please refer to this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/net-html/host-config